# PCI device driver exporting information to /proc file system

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, procfs

I was asked this question in an interview. You are writing a PCI driver and you want to export the hardware-related information to the /proc filesystem. The interesting thing is that I searched the driver code and I couldn't find any call related to /proc filesystem though actually the information is exported. Is it done automatically? What is the mechanism? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: What info is exported to /proc? Is it driver specific (e.g. something like author name) or device specific (e.g. something like bus, slot etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is for your driver to

- implement a function that will get called whenever a process reads the corresponding /proc entry with the following signature:

  > int (*read_proc)(char *page, char **start, off_t offset, int count, int *eof, void *data);
- register your function by passing its pointer to `create_proc_read_entry()`, which accepts the name of the /proc entry as a string among other things:

  > create_proc_read_entry("foobar", 0, NULL, your_read_func_ptr, NULL);

When your driver unloads, it should remove the entry with `remove_proc_entry()`

Answer (score 4):

Creating entries in the /proc pseudo-filesystem is explained in [Linux Device Drivers [3rd ed]](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), chapter 4.

Nowadays you probably want to consider using `sysfs` instead; it's covered in LDD3 chapter 14.